# Approach for Toggling A Property's Value Within Code Block in C#

Tags: c#

Every so often I come across the need to temporarily change the value of a property within a scope (code block), changing it back to its original value upon leaving that scope. This is something that's easily done using try/finally:

```
public void DoSomeWorkSampleA(IStatusBar statusBar)
{
    // capture current property value
    //
    var oldMessage = statusBar.Message;

    try
    {
        // replace current property value
        //
        statusBar.Message = "Doing some work...";

        // some lenghty operation happens here
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        // restore previous property value
        //
        statusBar.Message = oldMessage;
    }
}
```

But I'm looking for a solution that's reusable and more concise, e.g.:

```
public void DoSomeWorkSampleB(IStatusBar statusBar)
{
    using (PropertyToggler.Toggle(statusBar, property => statusBar.Message, withValue: "Doing some work..."))
    {
        // some lenghty operation happens here
        //
    }
}
```

Below is my current implementation, but something about it feels off (maybe it's that this is more trouble than it's worth given that Sample B only saves about 6 lines of code and is potentially confusing in its current form). Is there a better approach for this? Is there a solution that's right under my nose, obvious and easy?

```
public static class PropertyToggler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Toggles a type's property to the supplied value for the lifetime of the returned <see cref="IDisposable"/>,
    /// setting that property back to its original value upon <see cref="IDisposable.Dispose"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object containing the property to toggle</param>
    /// <param name="property">The property setter</param>
    /// <param name="withValue">Value for the property</param>
    /// 
    public static IDisposable Toggle<TPropertySource, TProperty>(TPropertySource source,
        Expression<Func<TPropertySource, TProperty>> property, TProperty withValue)
    {
        return new PropertyTogglerInternal<TPropertySource, TProperty>(source, property, withValue);
    }


    private sealed class PropertyTogglerInternal<TPropertySource, TProperty> : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TProperty _oldValue;
        private readonly TPropertySource _propertySource;
        private readonly Action<TPropertySource, TProperty> _propertySetter;

        private bool _alreadyDisposed;


        public PropertyTogglerInternal(TPropertySource propertySource, Expression<Func<TPropertySource, TProperty>> property, TProperty withValue)
        {
            _propertySource = propertySource;
            _oldValue = property.Compile().Invoke(propertySource);

            _propertySetter = GetPropertySetter(property);
            _propertySetter.Invoke(propertySource, withValue);
        }

        private static Action<TPropertySource, TProperty> GetPropertySetter(Expression<Func<TPropertySource, TProperty>> property)
        {
            var memberBody = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
            var propertyParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), "value");

            var setterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<TPropertySource, TProperty>>(
                Expression.Assign(memberBody, propertyParam), property.Parameters[0], propertyParam);

            return setterExpression.Compile();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!_alreadyDisposed)
            {
                // restore the old value
                //
                _propertySetter.Invoke(_propertySource, _oldValue);
            }

            _alreadyDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is another [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You are trying to display status text and decide what it is a good idea to remember previous status and now asking question about how to *pattern* that nicely. Then how about a case when 2 threads will try to change status at once, one will remember previous, but second -  already modified by one, now if second finished later you have problem. Normally there should be a `Add/Delete`: dictionary where key is a job id (`DateTime` ?) and value is message. Status (if it only shows one message) will simply display the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

Using try / finally for that purpose is an interesting way of doing what you want to achieve. What about this solution:

Instead of putting your routine into a `try`-block, you could as well put your routine(s) into a function that actually *returns* a `statusBar.Message`. By doing so, you can have more than one block and you could also use it to conditionally return an error message from a block if there's something wrong.